# When I use the "addContentView" and " layoutParams.topMargin",the latter is disabled. Why?

Tags: android

My code is as below :

```
RemindView remindView = new RemindView(this);
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
layoutParams.topMargin = ViewUtils.getViewHeight(view);
addContentView(remindView, layoutParams);
```

But the  margin attribute i.e `layoutParams.topMargin`is disabled. I want to know the cause of this problem. Please help.

Comment: Try using WindowManager.LayoutParams, not the LinearLayout one. The params should be of the type of parent you add the view to.

Comment: Where does `addContentView()` actually adds `remindView`? What layout is the parent of `remindView`?

Comment: The method of  addContentView() is activity's one. I want add the remindView to that.So its parent View is the decorView of  activity.